# Why does the text in TextView classes on API <= 23 disappear after setTextAppearance() is called?

Tags: android, api, textview, android-appcompat

UPDATE:

It appears what is happening is that on API <= 23, when the setTextAppearance() is called in the way I show below in my app, under the covers somewhere the text color gets changed to white. Since most of my use of TextView is on a white background, it looks like the text just 'disappeared'. Still don't understand WHY it does that, but that is what is going on...

---

In my app all activities are based on `AppCompatActivity`, and fragments are instances of `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`.

My app theme's parent is `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`. I have not modified any colors related to Text items in that theme, only items like `colorPrimary`, `colorAccent`, etc.

My app offers the ability to dynamically change font sizes ("normal", "larger") based on a preference setting, and a corresponding variable `isUsingNormalFontSize` is set appropriately that I reference in code.

In my layouts, most of the TextViews have as their default text appearance  `android.R.style.TextAppearance_Material_Small`.

If a user selects "larger" within my app's preferences, then in code wherever I use TextView (or classes built on that like EditText), I do the following:

```
if (!isUsingNormalFontSize) {
    loginErrorText.setTextAppearance(c, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Material_Medium);
}
```

My app targets API 30 within a minimum of 21. I have noticed that on API <=23, after executing the setTextAppearance() line, the text completely disappears. For example, here is the login screen that appears on first install of my app using API 24+:

[image]

And here it is on a device using API 21 using the exact same code flow:

[image]

(the "Forgot Password?" text shows on API 21 only because it is purposefully not changed in size or typeface dynamically the way the other TextViews are).

I have been able to effect a work-around which is somewhat painful by checking every place I do the change in text appearance to test for API <= 23 and explicitly setting a text color and hint color as needed, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

The method *setTextAppearance(Context context, int resId)* was deprecated in API 23.
[Here you can read for documentation of TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView). On the documentation recommends using the method [setTextAppearance (int resId)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setTextAppearance(int)).

Comment: Yes, thanks I'm aware of this. That doesn't really answer my question though. First, just because it is deprecated doesn't necessarily mean it "won't work". It means "might not work in future releases". Yet as I've shown that API is still fully functional through API 30.  Second, a device running API 21 should be able to run it just fine, no? Yet as I've shown it doesnt. At least for me in my app. That's what I'm trying to figure out!